# What does PSR-0 stand for?

Tags: php

I know what **PSR-0** is, and how, why, where to use it.

I've googled for this and looked around stackoverflow related posts, but **could not** find anything. Even on its [official page](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) there's no such definition.

So, the question is, **what does PSR-0 exactly stand for**?

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards) I would assume "Proposed Standards Recommendation", or maybe "PHP Standards Recommendation".

Comment: I can't answer due to the question being closed, but all of the existing answers appear to be wrong, which is frustrating. As far as I can see, the official expansion of the acronym has always been "PHP Standards Recommendation". I have opened [an issue to have this information added to the FAQ](https://github.com/php-fig/php-fig.github.com/issues/128) on http://www.php-fig.org/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

PSR stands for PHP Standard Recommendation as explained on http://www.php-fig.org/faqs/#what-does-psr-stand-for and here http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Answer (score 41):

PSR is a specification for defining a coding standard for PHP. Currently there are six accepted recommendations:

- [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)
- [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)
- [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)
- [PSR-3](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/)
- [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)
- [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)

each addressing a specific aspect of coding.

Answer (score 6):

> PSR, a PHP Specification Request, is an attempt to standardise the way
>   people use PHP in the hope that different sets of code libraries will
>   work together.
>   http://petermoulding.com/php/psr

Comment: Wrong, it's PHP Standard Recommendation (http://www.php-fig.org/faq/#what-does-psr-stand-for)

Answer (score 0):

PSR stands for Proposing a Standards Recommendation. I’m not sure if it’s used anywhere else, but in the current context it is part of PHP-FIG (PHP Framework Interoperability Group).

For further reference 
http://blog.jayawi.com/psr-0/